How to use DataSource bean when calling Hazelcast Sources.jdbc
I'm trying to create a Source for Hazelcast Jet based on an SQL query.
Instead of passing jdbc url directly, I want to use my DataSource registered in my Spring context.
And then, I want to create a source by calling
Sources.jdbc(newConnectionFn, newConnectionFn, createOutputFn)
So, I thought that my SupplierEx<Connection> should look like the class below and everything will be properly deserialized when Hazelcast instances receive this function:
@SpringAware
public class DataSourceBeanHolder implements SupplierEx<Connection>, ApplicationContextAware {
    @Autowired
    private transient DataSource dataSource;

    public DataSourceBeanHolder(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.dataSource = applicationContext.getBean(DataSource.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getEx() throws Exception {
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}

BatchSource<Long> source = Sources.jdbc(
            new DataSourceBeanHolder(dataSource),
            (con, parallelism, index) -> {
                PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT ID FROM MYTABLE WHERE  MOD(ID, ?) = ?)");
                stmt.setInt(1, parallelism);
                stmt.setInt(2, index);
                return stmt.executeQuery();
            },
            resultSet -> resultSet.getLong(1));

However, when I try to run this, the DataSourceBeanHolder is deserialized and neither the @Autowired field is set nor setApplicationContext is ever called. Hazelcast instances are crashing with NullPointerException in DataSourceBeanHolder.getEx()
What am I missing?
Why is DataSourceBeanHolder deserialized in a different way than other classes?

I did not forget about configuring SpringManagedContext.
I have already configured SpringManagedContext and it works correctly in other places. Even in Jet, I can use com.hazelcast.spring.jet.JetSpringServiceFactories#bean(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class<T>) with no issues.
config.setManagedContext(new SpringManagedContext(springContext));

This is a question about Sources.jdbc only and the parameter newConnectionFn
Hazelcast version: 5.4.0


This answer assumes that you ure using embedded hazelcast.
Store the DataSource in a singleton class
@Component
public class DataSourceProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {

  private static DataSource dataSource;

  @Override
  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    dataSource = applicationContext.getBean(DataSource.class);
  }

  public static DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
  }
}

Then use the singleton from a SupplierEx. The reason we are doing this is, SupplierEx is serialized and then deserialized when the job is submitted. When it is deserialized we need to be able to access DataSource again
public class NewConnectionProvider implements SupplierEx<Connection> {

  @Override
  public Connection getEx() throws Exception {
    DataSource dataSource = DataSourceProvider.getDataSource();
    return dataSource.getConnection();
  }
}

Then use in in Sources.jdbc
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JdbcSourceCommandLineRunner implements CommandLineRunner {

  private final HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) {
    BatchSource<Long> source = Sources.jdbc(
      new NewConnectionProvider(),
      (con, parallelism, index) -> {
        PreparedStatement stmt = con
          .prepareStatement("SELECT ID FROM MYTABLE WHERE  MOD(ID, ?) = ?)");
        stmt.setInt(1, parallelism);
        stmt.setInt(2, index);
        return stmt.executeQuery();
      },
      resultSet -> resultSet.getLong(1));

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();
    pipeline.readFrom(source)
      .writeTo(Sinks.logger());

    JetService jetService = hazelcastInstance.getJet();
    Job job = jetService.newJob(pipeline);
    job.join();
  }
}

I hope this helps

I was hoping for an answer that doesn’t require passing objects through a static field. I actually have a more complex Datasource setup both in prod and in tests.

@MateuszStefek you are not going to get it, we use exactly the same approach.
